# What are the easter eggs In Game Dev Tycoon?

Tags: game-dev-tycoon

I was looking through the Steam achievements for Game Dev Tycoon and noticed this one:

[image: Detective - Find at least one of the easter eggs in the game.]

After seeing this I started ruthlessly trying to click and stare at every little thing in the game but still can't find anything.  Can anyone at least give me some hints on what some of these easter eggs are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most of the easter eggs in Game Dev Tycoon revolve around games already made, or your company's name, naming your company after a 'well known' company nets you one, or making a specific game in a certain office also works. Like for example, while in the second office, naming a game Wing Commander gets an easter egg. (Needs to be before PC upgrade.) Or you can make a Game Dev Tycoon within Game Dev Tycoon. (Needs to be a Game Dev Sim.)